# How to use specific browser version after Selenium 4.6

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests

Starting with Selenium 4.6., [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) takes care of handling chromedriver/geckodriver by downloading the latest available version.

What do I need to do to use a specific version (instead of the latest one)?

Comment: if you are asking about the driver in Java it would be  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "[absolute_path_to_driver]");  
for chromedriver it'd be "webdriver.chrome.driver".  For the browser, you just specify the directory, ex: "options.setBinary([chrome_browser_absolute_path]);"  If it helps you, you can also turn off version checking in Chromedriver with: System.setProperty ("webdriver.chrome.disableBuildCheck", "true");

Answer (score 1):

The Selenium 4 documenation on this states:

> Driver management through Selenium Manager **is opt-in** for the Selenium
> bindings. Thus, users can continue managing their drivers manually
> (putting the driver in the PATH or using system properties) or rely on
> a third-party driver manager to do it automatically. **Selenium Manager**
> **only operates as a fallback: if no driver is provided**, Selenium
> Manager will come to the rescue.

[Source](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/#usage)

Using this documenation as a guide, if you continue to implement a process of manually specifying your own driver versions Selenium Manager should not be installing different / newer versions. If it is not functioning correctly, [you might need to consider logging a bug with Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/new/choose)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) to pair any driver version with the currently-installed Chrome version on your system.

Here's a sample script to run with `python` after `pip install seleniumbase`:

```py
import time
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(browser="chrome", driver_version="112")
driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/")
time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```

SeleniumBase automatically downloads the `driver_version` specified.

(Only Chrome is supported for the `driver_version` parameter right now.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the correct [BrowserOptions](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/), in your case `browserVersion`. In Java this would be something like this for Firefox:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

var caps = new FirefoxOptions();
caps.setCapability("browserVersion", "121.0.1");
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Or use this for Chrome browser:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

var options = new ChromeOptions();
caps.setCapability("browserVersion", "120");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

You don't need to specify the exact version. [SeleniumManager](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/) is going to pick the most suitable one if no exact match is found.

For more examples see selenium's [unit tests on github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/seleniumhq.github.io/tree/trunk/examples/java/src/test/java/dev/selenium/browsers).